# Manipulating image in canvas. How to make the source to remain secret

Tags: html, base64

I'm manipulating an image in the html5 canvas. The source-image is stored in a database as a base64. Is it possible to ensure this source-image remains hidden and secret for people visiting the website?

Right now I do a mysql query and pass the base64 string from php to the javascript. That's why it's easy to figure out the source-base64 string.

Maybe I need to do this otherwise. I hope you can give me some suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Not as long as you do the image processing on the users machine.

**Long answer:** Javascript is executed on the users machine. Almost all web browsers got debugging tool which allow the user to monitor what your javascript application is doing. You could encrypt your image data, but in order to process it, you will have to decrypt it sooner or later. Any user who knows a bit Javascript will be able to extract your image data at that moment.

You could make it harder through running your js code through an obfuscator. But that's not a reliable protection either. As long as it's machine-readable, it's human-readable. Someone who is determined enough will also dig through obfuscated code.

When you want the source image to stay secret, you have to do all image processing on the server, and send the processed image to the user.

Comment: I was afraid for this. Can canvas be used for this purpose or do I have to use the PHP GD library for doing the manipulation on the server?

Comment: Canvas is a Javascript/HTML5 feature. When you want to do it server-sided, you have to use what PHP has to offer.

Comment: that's clear. Do you have experience with the PHP GD library?

Comment: A bit, but that was a long time ago. When you need help with it, you should open a new question.